# Best datatype to return for XML serialized data

Tags: c#, serialization, interface, return-value

I am creating a generic Android to C# tcp stack. On the C# side I would like to implement an interface called ITcpSerializable.

The result of this serialization would then be sent over my tcp connection as raw xml.

The current definition is as such.

```
public interface ITcpSerializable
{
    StringBuilder Serialize();
}
```

However what I am wondering is what is the best return type for a method like `Serialize()` when you expect that on some occasions the dataset may be rather large.

It seems like there are so many alternatives for return types for such a method. Stream, textreader, xmldocument, perhaps even byte[] etc... What would be the best one??

PS: I realize this is somewhat subjective but am genuinely in need of some advice.

Comment: I normally prefer JSON over XML as it is smaller

Comment: I have considered that and may infact move to JSON at some point. Either way I think this question is relevant to whatever internal implementation you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are developing a component to be used by third-party then you better stick to the serialization pattern of .NET, google for an article of that.

I believe the answer will be to return byte[] but maybe you will learn more about the pattern if you will read an article.

If you are developing for yourself stick to whats working for you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are talking TCP, I would use a Stream pattern, not a return type - i.e.

```
void Read(Stream source);
void Write(Stream destination);
```

This is then format independent. However, for "separation of concerns" I would favour a separate serializer than objects that *also* know about serialization... Either it's job is to be an object model, or it's job is to know how to serialize things; rarely both.

Personally, on a socket I'd use something denser than XML though; I have very strong tendencies towards protobuf (but as an implementor (protobuf-net) I'm biased).